# Displaying Antarctica using GeoJSON in heremaps

Tags: javascript, geojson, here-api

I'm trying to render Antarctica geojson shape on a map using the HERE maps api.
The geojson is found here: https://github.com/johan/world.geo.json/blob/master/countries/ATA.geo.json
You can see github renders it nicely.
Using the same geojson on geojson.io also renders it nicely.

But somehow it seems to render the 'inverse' of Antarctica when using it in HERE maps.
It colors everything except antarctica. 
see: http://imagebin.ca/v/1dZIn5vsEuFx
(I've tried making an expample using jsfiddle, but it's not able to load external json. And the HERE maps api doesn't allow you to load geoJSON from a string)

Is there an issue with the geoJSON? Is there an issue with the HERE maps api?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The API doesn't quite understand what to do with the open polygon. Because the polygon is basically just a line around the globe the API doesn't know if you shape closes over the north pole or the south pole. By default it assumes that open polygons close over the north pole. You can change this by using this flag (setNorthPoleCovering):

http://developer.here.com/javascript-apis/documentation/v3/maps/topics_api_nlp/h-map-polygon.html#h-map-polygon__setnorthpolecovering

However, actually getting to that point in the code where this can be done is a bit complicated:

```js
// When you instantiate the geojson.Reader you can specify a function that 
// receives all objects the reader parsed. It is called when objects are 
// being rendered on the map. At that point we can look into the object and
// check whether it is Antarctica
var reader = new H.data.geojson.Reader('...ATA.geo.json', {
  style: function(obj) {
    if (obj.getData().properties.name === "Antarctica") {
      //AHA! We found Antarctica!
      // Since this is a multi-polygon we have a group here which contains
      // all polygons. We apply the north-pole-covering flag to each of the
      // polygons
      obj.forEach(function(polygon) {
        polygon.setNorthPoleCovering(false);
      });
    }
  }
});
reader.parse();
map.addLayer(reader.getLayer());
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you want to accomplish in terms of dynamic behavior, if you are just looking to display or share a map with cards and other metadata about a country with some basic styling -- [HERE XYZ](https://developer.here.com/blog/managing-and-visualizing-geospatial-data-here-xyz-now-in-beta) can be used to render GeoJSON on a HERE map.

[image: Antartica Test]

If you want to do it with JavaScript rather than an embedded iframe, the other answer may be what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

There is an there an issue with the GeoJSON, and other mapping APIs would have the same problem.  It needs to be closed at the 180th meridian, so

```
[178.277212,-84.472518],[180,-84.71338],[-179.942499,-84.721443]
```

becomes

```
[178.277212,-84.472518],[180,-84.71338],[180,-90],[-180,-90],[-180,-84.71338],[-179.942499,-84.721443]
```